# Ogg vorbis crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oggvorbis

I'm trying to add support for *Ogg Vorbis* in my project *(C++, VS 2010)*. I had no problem compiling *LibOgg + LibVorbis* to produce a static library.

My procedure is this:

**LibOgg**

- Download LibOgg
- Build LibOgg with dynamic solution (Release)
- Get a *libogg.lib* export and a *libogg.dll* in */Release* folder

**LibVorbis**

- Download LibVorbis
- Set appropriate *include + library* folders for *LibOgg*
- Build LibVorbis with dynamic solution (Release)
- Get a *libvorbis.lib* and *libvorbisfile.lib* exports and *libvorbis.dll* and *libvorbisfile.dll* in */Release* folder

**My program**

- Set appropriate *include + library* folders for *Libogg + LibVorbis* .lib exports
- Place *.dll* in working directory

The build succeeds but unlike the static build (which works), the dynamic build just crashes in the first `ov_open` call (which opens some .ogg file). I built lots of libraries *(GLEW, SQlite, etc.)* yet this one gives me the nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, i solve this.
It seems *OggVorbis* is touchy when it comes to *Windows* and use of `ov_open` due to some linking issues with *stdio.h* and `fopen`.

[Documentation](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/ov_open.html) says it clearly:

> WARNING for Windows developers: Do not use ov_open() in Windows
>   applications; Windows linking places restrictions on passing FILE *
>   handles successfully, and ov_open() runs afoul of these restrictions
>   [a]. See the ov_open_callbacks() page for details on using
>   ov_open_callbacks() instead.

Although it is recommended by docs to use callbacks, i found `ov_fopen` to be reliable which works for both static and dynamic builds with the OggVorbis; the dynamic build **will crash** your program if you use `ov_open` on *Windows*.

Going to update this answer after i test it against Linux and OSX to verify `ov_fopen` as a safe, all around solution.

**UPDATE**

As said, i tested the use of `ov_fopen` on *Windows 7, Linux (Lubuntu), OSX (10.8.2) and Android (KitKat 4.4.4)* and i found out that works reliably. So, for those allergic to callbacks (like me), `ov_fopen` proved reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I can't seem to find the default OV_CALLBACKS_DEFAULT that the docs say to pass instead. How do I work around this?

Comment: @rationalcoder, you can find the _default substitute_ for windows (as xiph says) in [this](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/ov_open_callbacks.html) page (look at notes below), and [here](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/callbacks.html) is some how to. If you mean it's _undeclared_, i have seen this too.. never found a solution since im using `ov_fopen`

Comment: Yep, I found that and I meant undeclared :( Unfortunately for me, so was ov_fopen!!! Luckily, however, I stumbled upon an old gamedev.net thread that posted a working implementation of the callbacks that use stdio.h. I am up and running now. +1 btw.

Comment: @rationalcoder, that's odd but happily you solved that out. As far as i remember, ogg is a bit confusing at first, since you need actually _two (2)_  libraries, the _ogg_ and _vorbis_. The vorbis **is** the one having _ov_x_ functionality and the majority of code, while ogg is essentially 2 sources files, producing a tiny library. Perhaps did you tried compiling only ogg? I remember merging up both library's sources and producing a standalone .lib and .a.

Comment: Nope, I am linking to both libraries and including the headers that the docs said that the symbols would be defined in. I searched the headers manually and found no such things! ov_fopen was supposed to be in vorbisfile.h, and it wasn't.